# Is Import-CSV useful for import of ;-separated code page 1252 files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I use

```
Import-Csv $mycsvFile
```

I get lines like

```
1;M�nchen;Bayern
```

The 2 problems are, that it doesn't understand the ansi codepage (i.e. has no parameter -encoding default) and I didn't succesd in using the -del parameter to tell it to use the ; as separator. Any suggestions?

Comment: I worked around the charset problem by using an utf-8 copy of my original file, but I still have no idea how to make the dokumented -Delimiter parameter work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 points to note to successfull use Import-CSV

1. the data has to include a line with headers or the headers must be supplied as parameter. Without either the errormessage isn't really helpfull
2. code page 1252 doesn't work, there is no -encoding parameter which offers default, as in similar other cmdlets.
3. After the first two points fullfiled, the -delimiter parameter works as described.
   [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347665.aspx)

I really thought about using gc and split to achieve my problem, where the data has about
20000 lines.

Here for demonstration I present a 1-line example:

Contents of DemoData.csv:

```
1;München;Bayern
```

Contents of Import-DemoData.ps1

```
$header = "id","Ort","Land"
Import-CSV C:\mydata\DemoData.csv -del ';' -head $header
```

Comment: Also remember that there is a ConvertTo-CSV that works on string input.